# Can I willingly expose my sandboxed files to another specified program?

Tags: ios

My app has several settings that it would be convenient to manipulate during testing. How this has been accomplished on other platforms is there is a separate control app that is used by testers to change the settings.

Is this possible on iOS? Is it possible for my app to expose its settings so they can be manipulated by a test app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Settings.bundle approach to expose your application's settings to the user. Alternatively, expose them using a regular UIView. These approaches work well with the standard NSUserDefaults class.

If you have implemented your settings functionality in a different manner, you will have major stumbling blocks to overcome, in addition to the extra code you'll have to write.

Comment: Also, the app sandbox is not there to be bypassed and it isn't easy for you to do so.

Comment: Thanks, however the settings are only changeable by testers, not by users (sorry didn't make that point clear). I've thought of making them available via the GUI during test build and not available during non test builds but don't like building a larger set of functionality via build switches into apps if it can be avoided

Answer (score 0):

Apps can share data in the keychain.

Comment: Hello David, could you please describe further how one app can access anothers keychain data.

Comment: You'll have to look it up, I just know it's possible for them to be in a suite. http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897

Answer (score 0):

You might try exposing the settings via a web service. Then you can run your app and update the settings via browser, command line etc.

Also frequently switching between the "settings app" and the app being tested could be cumbersome.

Side note: being familiar with adjusting an app's settings via web service is useful in general. For example if you want to turn some promotional content off/on in an app w/o having to update the app.

Answer (score 0):

The iOS Simulator exposes all app sandbox files to the Mac file system, where any Mac app (running from your same User account) can read or write them for testing.

Or, if you enable iTunes Document sharing, you can upload new file content to an iOS app's sandboxed Document directory on a device using iTunes.

Another method that requires significantly more work is to create a test stub (for Debug builds only) that connects outside the app via a network socket, and that can read or control selected variables or files via some homebrew protocol.